# Como borrar datos de múltiples tablas en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo varias tablas las cuales hago un `SELECT` usando `FULL OUTER JOIN` para traer datos aunque haya campos `NULL`.

Bien, lo que quiero es tener un `DELETE` que me borre los clientes que tengan el campo `Monto` en `NULL`, el cual esta en la tabla `Prestamo`.

Estas son mis tablas:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En resumen,si el campo Monto Tiene `NULL`, entonces borrar los clientes que lo tengan así.

Este es el código con que llamo los datos que quiero de las diferentes tablas.

```
SELECT    Cliente.Nombre, Cuenta.Tipo, Prestamo.Monto AS monto_del_prestamo, 
Prestamo.Saldo, PagoPrestamo.Monto AS monto_pago_prestamo, 
PagoPrestamo.Fecha, Prestamo.CantidadCuota

FROM            Cliente FULL OUTER JOIN
                     Cuenta ON Cliente.IdCliente = Cuenta.IdCliente FULL 
OUTER JOIN
                     Prestamo ON Cuenta.IdCuenta = Prestamo.IdCuenta FULL 
OUTER JOIN
                     PagoPrestamo ON Prestamo.IdCuenta = 
PagoPrestamo.IdCuenta

go
```

Comment: En tu diagrama, el cliente no aparece en la tabla `cuenta`. Por otro lado, no puedes borrar datos de muchas tablas en un sólo comando SQL (a menos que hayas creado relaciones en cascada entre tus tablas)

Comment: De que tabla queres borrar al cliente?

Comment: Por lo que veo no es complejo lo que requieres, si quieres eliminar de Clientes los registros que no tienen datos en PagoPrestamo (por ello salen en NULL), En la query que tienes, solo debes hacer SELECT DISTINCT al campo "Cliente.Id" he incluir la clausula "WHERE PagoPrestamo.Monto IS NULL". Esta SELECT va a ser tu sub consulta, por lo que quedaría algo así, [DELETE FROM Cliente WHERE Id IN ("Tu consulta con las modificaciones que indique")]. Para poder ayudarte con toda la consulta que debes ejecutar necesito que me confirmes si tu tabla Cliente tiene un campo relacionado  Fk - idCuenta

Comment: @Lamak Perdon,se me paso eso.En realidad si lo tengo,pasa que ya había modificado eso.En la tabla Cuenta tengo como FK el IdCliente de la tabla Cliente.

Comment: @CarmeloGassette Perdon por ese error,fue que no me había dado cuenta de que puse la imagen incorrecta.La correcta viene siendo la misma pero con el IdCliente como FK en la tabla Cuenta.Voy a modificar el post.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481379/how-to-delete-using-inner-join-with-sql-server

```
begin tran
DELETE w
FROM WorkRecord2 w
INNER JOIN Employee e
ON EmployeeRun=EmployeeNo
WHERE Company = '1' AND Date = '2013-05-06'
select * from WorkRecord2; /* esto seria para ver los valores que cambiaron sin aplicar aun la transaccion */
rollback tran
```

como vez cada tabla tiene un alias solo coloca el alias de la tabla que quieres borrar.
puedes colocar begin tran y rollback tran para evitar errores, 
ahora si te hace muy complejo puedes utilizar un "in" con el id cliente que quieres borrar 
algo así como:

```
delete from clientes 
where idCliente in (select id cliente
           from todaTuConsulta);
```

Answer (score 0):

Como primera opción, puedes mantener la lógica de tu consulta original dentro de un *CTE* y hacer el borrado sobre la tabla cliente utilizando el operador `in` y una sub-consulta que devuelva el *id* de los clientes que tienen el campo de tu interés en `null`, de la siguiente manera:

```
with
Base as (
/* tu consulta original */
SELECT    Cliente.Nombre, Cuenta.Tipo, Prestamo.Monto AS monto_del_prestamo, 
Prestamo.Saldo, PagoPrestamo.Monto AS monto_pago_prestamo, 
PagoPrestamo.Fecha, Prestamo.CantidadCuota

FROM            Cliente FULL OUTER JOIN
                     Cuenta ON Cliente.IdCliente = Cuenta.IdCliente FULL 
OUTER JOIN
                     Prestamo ON Cuenta.IdCuenta = Prestamo.IdCuenta FULL 
OUTER JOIN
                     PagoPrestamo ON Prestamo.IdCuenta = 
PagoPrestamo.IdCuenta
)
delete
  from cliente 
 where idCliente in (select idCliente
                       from Base
                      where monto_del_prestamo is null);
```

La ventaja de esta técnica es que, sin importar lo compleja que sea tu sentencia original (por ejemplo, puede tener condiciones en el where o involucrar muchas tablas), no tienes que hacer más que encerrarla en un CTE y partir de ella, por lo que se hace bastante sencillo producir la solución final a partir de los pasos intermedios.

Otra posible solución es dar una vuelta más de tuerca y cambiar la pregunta. Voy a asumir que, de la consulta original, los clientes que tienen el campo en `null`, son los que no tienen préstamos, por lo que se puede construir una sentencia *ad-hoc* para la tarea del borrado, esta vez, por ejemplo, con el operador `not exists` y una sub consulta para determinar si un cliente tiene al menos un préstamo.

```
delete 
  from Cliente
 where not exists (select 1
                     from Cuenta 
                          inner join Prestamo on Prestamo.idCuenta = Cuenta.idCuenta
                    where Cuenta.idCliente = Cliente.idCliente);
```

La principal ventaja de esta última, en mi opinión, es que es más legible y fácil de mantener. También puede ser que tenga un mejor desempeño en conjuntos de datos grandes.

Comment: Disculpa,pero intento con la segunda solución y me da error.
Me dice esto:  "Instrucción DELETE en conflicto con la restricción REFERENCE "FK_Cuenta_Cliente". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "Banco", tabla "dbo.Cuenta", column 'IdCliente'. "   Me parece que es la clave foránea en la tabla 'Cuenta' la que da ese error.Y por cierto no entiendo lo del 1 en esa consulta.

Comment: Hola. El error del delete efectivamente es porque hay clientes que no tienen préstamo, pero tienen alguna cuenta y tu llave foránea está impidiendo que se eliminen. Hay varias soluciones para eso, pero quedan fuera del alcance de la pregunta original y cuál sea la correcta depende de lo que realmente quieras conseguir.

Comment: Con respecto al `select 1`, ya que utilizo la sub-consulta en un operador `not exists`, la utilizo regularmente para evitar la sobrecarga de tener que ir a recuperar algún dato de la fila, pues realmente solo quiero evaluar si la consulta devuelve un resultado vacío.

Comment: Y que tengo que hacer entonces con respecto a la llave foránea?

Comment: Si lo que quieres es eliminar los clientes, aunque tengan cuenta(s), puedes a) Eliminar manualmente las cuentas de estos clientes, siguiendo una técnica similar. b) Puedes modificar el constraint de la llave foránea con un `on delete cascade`, para que al eliminarse el cliente, automáticamente se eliminen las cuentas.